# I don't know using python aiomysql normally. running time (when aiomysql doesn't use) is same running time when aiomysql uses

Tags: python, mysql, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I use aiomysql. I access mysql with asynchronous. SO I use aiomysql.
But running time(when aiomysql doesn't use) is same running time when aimysql uses.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:"+"qhdks12#$"+"@localhost/stock", encoding='utf-8')
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password="qhdks12#$", db='stock', charset='utf8')
cursor = conn.cursor()
def test():
    for i in range(10):
        sql = "select * from test;"     
        data = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, index_col=None)
%timeit test()
```

Above Code, aiomysql not use. In Jupyter Notebook, test() function running time is "3.1 s ± 39.3 ms"

```
import asyncio
import aiomysql as aiomysql
import pandas as pd

async def main(loop):

    pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', password='qhdks12#$', db='stock', loop=loop)
    for i in range(2):
        await test(pool, loop)

async def test(pool, loop):
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute("select * from test;")
            rows = ()
            rows = await cur.fetchall()
            result = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(rows))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
%timeit loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Above Code, aiomysql use. In Jupyter Notebook, main(loop) function running time is "3.05 s ± 107 ms per loop "

Running time is same. I think above code doesn't connect db with asynchronous.

So, I don't know aiomysql normally. How do I connect db with asynchronous???

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Why do you expect different times?

Comment: Querying a database running on the same server is often going to be too quick to see any benefit from using an asynchronous driver. Also, this isn’t a good test for asyncio’s performance; you are effectively running synchronous code but with the overhead of the event loop.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is synchronous. If you read it out loud you are looping and waiting for each test to complete before continuing.

```
for i in range(2):
    await test(pool, loop)
```

To send your requests asynchronously you use wait or gather to wait on all of them.

```
futures = []
for i in range(10):
  futures.append( test(pool) )

done, pending = await asyncio.wait( futures, timeout=2 )
```